# Questions on notation that I haven't seen before (tensor product sign in superscript and mysterious $\Gamma$ symbol)

Tags: manifolds, tensor-products, tensors, vector-bundles, tangent-bundle

I have some questions about the Wikipedia article on Tensor fields. The definition of a tensor field is given as such:

---

Let $\mathfrak M$ be a manifold, for instance the Euclidean plane $\mathbb R^n$.

**DEFINITION:** A tensor field of type $(p, q)$ is a section

\begin{align}
 T \in \Gamma( \mathfrak M , V^{\otimes p} \otimes (V^*) ^{\otimes q})
\end{align}
where v is the vector bundle on $\mathfrak M$, $V^*$ is its dual and $\otimes$ is the tensor product of vector bundles.

---

**(a)**

Is the $^{\otimes p,q}$ analogous to the $^n$ in cartesian product $\mathbb R ^n$? That is, we take the tensor product of $V$ with itself $p, q$ times? Concretely, would writing $V^{\otimes 3}$ expand to $V \otimes V \otimes V$.

**(b)**

The editor gave some definitions, but neglected to write what $\Gamma$ is intended to mean. I haven't seen $\Gamma$ used in this context before, and I have read some books which involve manifolds and vector bundles. I would highly appreciate someone telling me what it is meant to represent.

Thank you in advance for help with both of these questions.

Comment: (a)- correct. (b) $\Gamma$ denotes the space of sections of a bundle.

Comment: @MoisheKohan ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert my comment to a proper answer.

(a) Your understanding is correct.

(b) If $\xi: E\to B$ is a bundle (a smooth vector bundle in your case) then $\Gamma(\xi)$ or, sometimes, $\Gamma(B, E)$, denotes the space of sections of this bundle (in your case, the space of smooth sections).